# Need to Show marker location in a specific country and show marker name

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working in a C# project where I have my `latitude` and `longitude`. I have already marked that location. The output is showing  a big screen map of world. I just need to show my country by auto zoom or only my country map.

And another thing is i can not show the names of my marked location. I wanted to show the IDs of my `latitude` and `longitude`. Such as ID 1 have `23.777176, 90.399452 point`. So the marked position title would be 1. Also I want to add picture of that ID which is in `.jpg format. My code is below. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                        function initialize() {
                          if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(45.05,7.6667), 2); 
                            " + Locations + @"
                            map.setUIToDefault();
                          }
                        }
                        </script>
```